# If $f(z)^N$ is analytic then $f(z)$ is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

I am a beginner in Complex Analysis:

Question from Gamelin Complex Analysis:

> If $f$ is continuous on a domain $D$ and $f(z)^N$ is analytic for some $N\in \Bbb N,$ then show that $f(z)$ is analytic too.

HINT:Use zeros of analytic function are isolated.

Attempt:

Let $z_0\in D$ then either $f(z_0)=0$ or $f(z_0)\neq 0$.

**CASE I** : $f(z_0)=0$.

If $f(z_0)= 0\implies f(z_0)^N=0\implies z_0$ is a zero of $f^N$ and hence $\exists r>0$ such that $f^N(z_0)\neq 0\forall 0<|z-z_0|<r$.

**What should I do now?**

**CASE II** :$f(z_0)\neq 0$.

I am totally confused how to proceed.

Comment: See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/831121/show-f-is-analytic-if-f8-is-analytic

Comment: @MartinR how so?

Comment: @OpenBall: Sorry, my fault.