# Be $f$ a Continuous function in $D$ and $f^8$ holomorphic in $D$. Show that $f$ is holomorphic in $D$

Tags: complex-analysis

Be $f$ a continuous function in $\mathbb D$ (the unit circle) and $f^8$ holomorphic in $\mathbb D$. Show that $f$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb D$.

I'm having difficulty with this problem. Would greatly appreciate suggestions on how to solve it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show $f$ is analytic if $f^8$ is analytic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/831121/show-f-is-analytic-if-f8-is-analytic) – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24f%5E8%24&p=1)

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is the zero function then there is nothing to prove. So I'll assume $f$ is not the constant function $0$.

Let $z_0\in D$ for which $f(z_0)\ne 0$. By continuity there is some open neighborhood $U$ of $z_0$ such that $f(U)$ is contained in half a plane. (it could be either upper or lower half and it could be right or left half). In half of the plane there is a branch of logarithm, hence also a branch of $8$th square root. This branch is holomorphic, and then $f=\sqrt[8]{f^8}$ is holomorphic in $U$ as a composition of holomorphic functions. So $f$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $z_0$.

Now, since every zero of $f$ is a zero of $f^8$ we conclude that all the zeros of $f$ must be isolated. (because $f^8$ is holomorphic and not the constant zero function by our assumption). Also, by continuity $f$ is locally bounded. Hence all the points $z\in D$ for which $f(z)=0$ are removable singularities, and hence $f$ is holomorphic in all $D$.